# convert an image server side to CanvasPixelArray

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**edit**

so it looks like i have to somehow convert an image to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasPixelArray
serverside

**my current attempts have been to ***

Pass a base64 encoded image from the server ... then converting it to binary with `atob()`

but then i get stuck trying to draw this onto a canvas without having to do something like

```
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function(){.....}
i.src = "base64 string"
```

**So an even more general statement**

I am trying to bypass creating a Image object by any means to display a new image

Comment: Why ? This image isn't displayed if you don't want to.

Comment: i am going to draw it on the canvas..

Comment: To use an Image as a decoder (and memory buffer) is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Make image src to http URL pointing to the server and you have your binary image

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid the use of javascript and to simply embed the image in your page, you can simply do

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,UhhIaminbase64...">
```

If your base64 is obtained dynamically in ajax, then the way to use the decoding library is to create an Image object with the code you made.

An alternate solution would be to send directly the RGB values in a binary array (base64 encoded if you use json) and to iterate client-side on this array in order to change your canvas' imageData. That seems easy enough but somewhat inefficient as you wouldn't have the compression of PNG or JPEG.

Comment: Yes, no real javascript object but I don't think the difference in memory between the js object and the internal image buffer is more than a few octets. I'm not sure about your exact goal. I hope it's not some kind of optimization.

Comment: So basicly you need an image without an image?!? The other option is to write your own base64 decoder and image render, which will cost more memory and cpu than using the browser's abilities.

Comment: Base64 isn't the problem, that's cheap. The problem would be to try to render a compressed format like png or jpeg. There it sure would cost cpu and memory.

Comment: hey @dystroy cool so iterating over the array seems to be the solution... but i guess i am not sure how to iterate over the base64 encoded image and get the pixel data

Answer (score 0):

With html5 you can do so:

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
document.body.appendChild(img);
};
</script>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZaUu/3/

Comment: yeah... so this is exactly what i dont want to do.. because we are creating an image object in JS